# How can I connect to Exchange online (connect-exopssession) with credentials and no form?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've tried a couple of variants of this (all 3 shown below). With this code, if I specify a value for  `-UserPrincipalName` a form will pop up quickly and disappear, fast enough to where only the form borders are rendered. If I do not specify a value for `-UserPrincipalName`, that same form opens and asks for me to sign in with my email address. The third option I tried was with `-Credential` and a credential object, I get the error:

> *"New-ExoPSSession : missing_federation_metadata_url: Federation Metadata Url is missing for federated user. This user type is
>   unsupported."* .

My end goal here is to authenticate without the form popping up so I can run some code with a scheduled task, which right now will not work because of the form and interactive mode. I can use creds, NO MFA and need to supress this form
somehow.

How can I connect to Exchange Online without this form appearing? Is there a way to use `New-PSsession` or `Import-PSsession`, or to wrap the `New-ExoPSSession` in something that prevents it from opening a form?

(Also, we need an "exchange-online" tag added, I don't have enough reputation to do so)

[image]

```
[string] $ConnectionUri = "https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveId"
[string] $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri = 'https://login.windows.net/common'       
[System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSSessionOption] $PSSessionOption = $null
[switch] $BypassMailboxAnchoring = $false
[string] $DelegatedOrganization = ''


$PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -UserPrincipalName "xxx@xxx.xxx" -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri -PSSessionOption $PSSessionOption -BypassMailboxAnchoring:$BypassMailboxAnchoring -DelegatedOrg $DelegatedOrganization

$PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri -PSSessionOption $PSSessionOption -BypassMailboxAnchoring:$BypassMailboxAnchoring -DelegatedOrg $DelegatedOrganization

$user = "xxx@xxx.xxx";
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force;
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($user, $password)
$PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -UserPrincipalName "xxx@xxx.xxx" -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri -Credential $creds -PSSessionOption $PSSessionOption -BypassMailboxAnchoring:$BypassMailboxAnchoring -DelegatedOrg $DelegatedOrganization
```

Comment: I am too facing this issue? Have you found any solution to it? Its weired that manually running the script works fine and in task scheduler it fails. I tested this considering many things like, 1. Cloud only account - works 2. If account is federated using ADFS - works 3. If account is federated using Ping Federate - Fails

Comment: @Jeetcu I had to have a cloud only service account created. I believe using app registration and a client secret cert is a possibility also, however I have not had time to put a test case together.

Comment: Yeah... Cloud only account and app registration does the job. But federated accounts not working.